# Evil Mode in Emacs 24 tab completes case-sensitively using :ed command

Tags: vim, emacs, tab-completion

I've been using EVIL with Emacs 24.3 for a few weeks now, and I wish I could get it to tab complete case-insensitively in the minibuffer when using the :ed command.

I looked into it, and :ed is mapped to `'evil-edit`, a function that essentially calls Emacs's `'find-file` function with a 'file' argument if said argument is present. Otherwise, it reloads the current buffer.

I did a little reading into `'find-file` as well, but I'm not having any luck figuring out why it won't be case-insensitive. The `'read-file-name-completion-ignore-case'` variable is non-nil, so it's not that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the evil list if you don't get an answer here: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation

Comment: Just let you know I have already posted on the [evil list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation/2145), but no answer yet.